# How to Change Raspberry pi 3 Boot order to Network boot with SD card Inserted

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, boot-issues, bootloader, berryboot

In Raspberry Pi 3 board, I am able to boot from network by changing the boot order to Network Modes as below :

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `echo program_usb_boot_mode=1 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt`
4. `sudo reboot`
5. `vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 17:`
6. `17:3020000a - OTP Successfully Modified`

My Problem is that the above works perfectly Fine when SD card is **NOT** Inserted in SD card SLOT, I want to **Boot from network even though SD card is Inserted,**

Currently the SD card is getting booted and unable to use network boot,
please guide me on how to boot from network even though SD card Inserted.

Comment: perhaps you're after [gpio boot mode](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#gpio-boot-mode)

Comment: Remove all the bootable files `kernel*.img` `start*.elf` and `fixup*.dat` from your SDCard and it shouldn't affect your other method of booting.

Comment: Why do you want network boot if you have SD Card? Alternately why do you want a SD Card if you have network boot?

Comment: thanks for the response, i need to skip sd card because through network boot i want format and flash new OS to Client SD card

Comment: i am able to switch to network boot by log-in to pi3  from another pi3 with below steps 1 > Login to server pi  and then ssh login to the test pi3 for which we want to format sdcard 2 > Format test pi3 using DD command -> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M status=progress3 > poweroff and poweron manually, now the sdcard detection is skipped as we formatted 4 > now through network boot i am able to flash new OS to old OS SD card, i am able to achieve, but  please guide me for the below 1 > used DD to format running OS , is create problem in OS stability, working on  Dougie reply .